# Kripke semantics for fuzzy logics

Tags: lo.logic

I am interested in Fuzzy logic.
I have a problem about Gödel Logic, I'm studying Kripke semantics for fuzzy logics and have found the necessary and sufficient conditions on Kripke frames for satisfying the axioms of BL that Hajek has wrote them in his book(Metamathematics of fuzzy logics). I guess that for the axiom(A5a) we need to have a reflexive Kripke frame but I couldn't proof the converse of that!
Who can help me please?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a little more context and, in particular, tell us explicitly what the axiom says?

Comment: Sorry, I had no internet connection,

Comment: The axiom says for every formula  P,Q and R we have [P-->(Q-->R)]---->[(P&Q)-->R], in addition in this logic every node k satisfies (p-->q) if for all k' R k  , if k' satisfies p then k' satisfies q.